# Agent Handoff intermediator-bot-sample (c#) by tompaana on github doesn't work on upgrading Microsoft.Bot.Builder and related packages to Ver 4.10.3

Tags: botframework, asp.net-core-middleware

## Problem Statement

This is regarding the Live Agent Handoff intermediator-bot-sample (c#) created by tompaana at https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample on guithub.

- **The intermediator-bot-sample works perfectly with Microsoft.Bot.Builder (4.2.2)** and Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core(4.2.2) and dependent Version 4.2.2 packages but, ***It does not use Dialogs.***
- **The HandoffMiddleware Code stopped getting invoked** , when I added the package *Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs (4.10.3)* (**as my ***existing*** code requires Dialogs**)  .  This also caused **upgrading to Microsoft.Bot.Builder to version 4.10.3** along with it's dependent packages i.e. Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core etc..

## Community Support

The Original Author Handoff intermediator-bot-sample [Tomi Paananen A.K.A tompaana](https://github.com/tompaana)  has moved on to other projects and would no longer be able to devote time to this project and has requested to reach out MS Botframework community members for support ([Refer: Author Response to Github issue raised](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample/issues/59)).

- **Requesting** BotFramework community to please help out to add Agent Hand Off functionality to my existing Chatbot

## Observation :

- Even After Package upgrade, the ***HandoffMiddleware class*** is getting successfully instantiated during Startup.
- My retrofitted code contains BotController class via which all the API  get invoked.  This BotController class which isn't present in the original Handoff intermediator-bot-sample code.
- On typing any utterance on the chat bot (Upgraded/new code), the **control goes** into the **BotController** class **rather than** invoking/triggering ***HandoffMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(...)***
- As the **original intermediator-bot-sample code** does not have any BotController/ API Controller, could this be the reason that utterances aren't getting routed via, ***HandoffMiddleware*** ***Middleware***   if so, ***how could I fix the issue?***

```
// Licensed under the MIT License.
//
// Generated with Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio EchoBot v4.6.2

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;

namespace Neo.Controllers
{
    // This ASP Controller is created to handle a request. Dependency Injection will provide the Adapter and IBot
    // implementation at runtime. Multiple different IBot implementations running at different endpoints can be
    // achieved by specifying a more specific type for the bot constructor argument.
    [Route("api/messages")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter Adapter;
        private readonly IBot Bot;

        public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
        {
            Adapter = adapter;
            Bot = bot;
        }

        [HttpPost, HttpGet]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
            await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
        }
    }
}
```

## Referenced Packages

### Original intermediator-bot-sample referenced Packages

[image: Original intermediator-bot-sample referenced Packages]

### Upgraded intermediator-bot-sample referenced Packages

[image]

### Original intermediator-bot-sample Solution Files

[image]

### Upgraded intermediator-bot-sample Solution Files

[image]

## Query

Could you please suggest How I can fix this issue?

- As the  ***HandoffMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(..)* works fine** when I execute **the coriginal code_** but, ***doesn't get triggered from* My Code** after retrofitting IntermediateBot code with **upgraded Microsoft.Bot.Builder** and **related packages** to ***Version 4.10.3*** .
- Pointing to an existing working Agent HandOff sample(c#) would also help

Answer (score 1):

### The following solution makes the upgraded Tompanna Agent Handoff solution work smoothly:

- The solution lies in the way BotFrameworkHttpAdapter needs to invoke HandoffMiddleware.

[The inspection Middleware](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/47.inspection) example in Github provides the methodology to invoke any middleware i.e. in those scenarios where we have the  upgraded Microsoft.Bot.Builder and related packages which introduce the concept of BotController class / API Controller .

### Code reference of AdapterWithInspection.cs from [BotBuilder-Samples/samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/47.inspection/AdapterWithInspection.cs)

> Replace ***InspectionMiddleware*** in the following code with  ***HandoffMiddleware***

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class AdapterWithInspection : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
    {
        public AdapterWithInspection(IConfiguration configuration, InspectionState inspectionState, UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger)
            : base(configuration, logger)
        {
            // Inspection needs credentiaols because it will be sending the Activities and User and Conversation State to the emulator
            var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);

//***********************************************************************************//
//* InspectionMiddleware needs to be replace HandOffMddieWare in the execution pipeline *// 
//***********************************************************************************//          
              Use(new InspectionMiddleware(inspectionState, userState, conversationState, credentials));

            OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
            {
                // Log any leaked exception from the application.
                logger.LogError(exception, $"[OnTurnError] unhandled error : {exception.Message}");

                // Send a message to the user
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("The bot encountered an error or bug.");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.");

                // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in the Bot Framework Emulator
                await turnContext.TraceActivityAsync("OnTurnError Trace", exception.Message, "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error", "TurnError");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

### New code should look like the following

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.


namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class AdapterWithInspection : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
    {
        public AdapterWithInspection(IConfiguration configuration, InspectionState inspectionState, UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger)
            : base(configuration, logger)
        {
            // Inspection needs credentials because it will be sending the Activities and User and Conversation State to the emulator
            var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);

//***********************************************************************************//
//*************** Adding HandOffMddieWare in the execution pipeline *****************//           
//***********************************************************************************//
            Use(new HandoffMiddleware(configuration));

            OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
            {
                // Log any leaked exception from the application.
                logger.LogError(exception, $"[OnTurnError] unhandled error : {exception.Message}");

                // Send a message to the user
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("The bot encountered an error or bug.");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.");

                // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in the Bot Framework Emulator
                await turnContext.TraceActivityAsync("OnTurnError Trace", exception.Message, "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error", "TurnError");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

### NOTE

- ***You would need to inject dependencies in the Startup.cs accordingly***

### Inject Dependencies in Startup.cs

> Add following code to facilitate dependency injection of AdapterWithInspection

```
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithInspection>();
```