# Botframework V4 Middleware does not get invoked when BotController Class is added

Tags: botframework, asp.net-core-middleware

Middleware classes of chatbot made in Botframework V4 worked perfectly.

**But, on upgrading Botbuilder and related packages, introduced BotController class / API Controller and now MiddleWare class is no longer invoked and BotController seems to be working as middleware.**

- How do I fix this so that, the Middleware gets invoked despite BotController class / API Controller ?
- Would appreciate support as, am stuck with this for quite some time :(
- Is  this related to some sequencing which needs to be done in the Startup.cs .. **Pls. Help**

Comment: Order can matter in startup. Have you tried moving things around and testing? Can you Share what you currently have?

Comment: Thanks @DanaV :)  <br/> Have been able to resolve the issue and have mentioned it in my other posts : <br/> 1. [ Click here link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151304/agent-handoff-intermediator-bot-sample-c-by-tompaana-on-github-doesnt-work-o) <br/>    2. [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114930/botframework-middleware-does-not-get-invoked-when.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Have been able to resolve this one. The solution is posted in my following posts:**

1. [Agent Handoff intermediator-bot-sample (c#) by tompaana on github doesn't work on upgrading Microsoft.Bot.Builder and related packages to Ver 4.10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151304/agent-handoff-intermediator-bot-sample-c-by-tompaana-on-github-doesnt-work-o)
2. [MS Botframework V4 (c#) Middleware does not get invoked when BotController Class is added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114930/botframework-middleware-does-not-get-invoked-when.html)