# Bot Handoff integration with teams

Tags: c#, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am working with bot handoff integration with teams. I have go through some Microsoft samples and seen some solutions.
one Solution is intermediate bot sample integration with teams and other one is using the handoff sdk to initiate the bot handoff and using a third party portal to connect with live agent.
Below are the solutions which i have followed.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples

https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

Could someone help me whats the best approach(Microsoft recommended one) to do the bot handoff integration with teams.

Comment: With respect to the tompaana sample, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151304/agent-handoff-intermediator-bot-sample-c-by-tompaana-on-github-doesnt-work-o/64193704#64193704 which was answered recently. On a general note, you can refer to the above-linked samples, https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I'm about to start essentially the same project so any leads would be helpful.