# Bot Framework - Handoff conversation to a live agent in Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have built a support QNA chatbot with the **Microsoft Bot Framework v4** on Javascript. We have managed to handoff the conversation to a live agent in a web chat when the bot doesn't have the right answer.

Our requirements are to **handoff the conversion to a live support agent in Microsoft Teams**. We saw there is an example of how to do this somewhere in Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/handoff-teams

The problem is that this uses a marketplace app designed for healthcare and we cannot find any documentation on how to do this without this management portal or how we can set up the handoff on our own.

Any bit of information regarding this use case would help. Thanks!

Comment: You can follow a experimental sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library). If are not able to implement that we have one more sample created by community member [here](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample).

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183879/bot-handoff-integration-with-teams#

Comment: Similar, but we use Javascript. I just updated my question to include this detail. Thanks!

Comment: There is no JavaScript sample available yet. You could check C# sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app) and implement the same in JavaScript.

Comment: If you are looking for javascript samples look this example https://github.com/GeekTrainer/botframework-v4-handoff